# Google Form Start Time and end time

Tags: forms, time, timestamp

Is there a native feature or method within Google Forms to capture the start time of a form/survey submission? I've explored Google Apps Script options but encountered difficulties in capturing the form's start time directly within the form itself. Any guidance or insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

I tried using Google Apps Script to capture the start time of a form or survey submission within Google Forms itself. My aim was to access the time when a respondent begins answering the form questions and then record that start time within the form submission data or in the linked Google Sheet in a seperate column or if it is feasible to capture the start and end time of the each question.

I expected that by leveraging the onFormSubmit() trigger in Google Apps Script, I could access the event object (e) and retrieve the start time information from the form submission. However, despite various attempts and script adjustments, I encountered difficulties in accurately capturing the start time directly within the form or storing it alongside the form submission data.

I sought to find a way to retrieve this start time information as part of the form submission process, either by using built-in functionalities or through scripting options, but so far, I haven't been successful in achieving this specific functionality within Google Forms.